# OPTIMIZE DATA SPOOLING FROM THE DATABASE

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm currently working with a team to create an application that gets its data from the database and posts it in the dashboard(user end). The application gets over a million data daily. 
After deploying to the clients, we're facing difficulties with getting results on the Dashboard creates a downtime and affects performance, the data's are in database, columns are indexed in the database, running a query on the DB is now extremely slow, takes over 5 mins to run a query

Comment: You should at least post table structure/query/volumetry of data and service tier. "columns are indexed in the database, running a query on the DB is now extremely slow" - I am guessing query is  not SARGable or it is blocked by other query.

Comment: Hi,did you see my answer? If my answer can be helps, could please accept or vote it? Thanks and have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database is an automatically managed and flexible data service where you can easily monitor usage, add or remove resources (CPU, memory, I/O), find recommendations that can improve performance of your database, or let database adapt to your workload and automatically optimize performance.

Monitoring the performance of a SQL database in Azure starts with monitoring the resource utilization relative to the level of database performance you choose. Azure SQL Database enables you to identify opportunities to improve and optimize query performance without changing resources by reviewing performance tuning recommendations. Missing indexes and poorly optimized queries are common reasons for poor database performance. You can apply these tuning recommendations to improve performance of your workload. You can also let Azure SQL database to automatically optimize performance of your queries by applying all identified recommendations and verifying that they improve database performance.

Fore more details, please reference: [Monitoring and performance tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-monitor-tune-overview#waiting-related-performance-issues). It gives you many suggestions about Azure SQL Database performance optimize.

You also can use the [Automatic tuning in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-automatic-tuning).

Automatic tuning is a fully managed intelligent performance service that uses built-in intelligence to continuously monitor queries executed on a database, and it automatically improves their performance. This is achieved through dynamically adapting database to the changing workloads and applying tuning recommendations. Automatic tuning learns horizontally from all databases on Azure through AI and it dynamically improves its tuning actions. The longer an Azure SQL Database runs with automatic tuning on, the better it performs.

Azure SQL Database Automatic tuning might be one of the most important features that you can enable to provide stable and peak performing database workloads.

Hope this helps.